# проверка полей на заполненость

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода, проверка

Ребят доброй ночи!
Подскажите , пишу проверку полей на заполненность в табах, нужно что бы пока поля не заполнены нельзя было переключаться на другой таб.
Переключение выполняется кнопкой "Далее"

Вот что навоял, вроде работает но может можно это дело как то сократить?

```js
function check() {
  var summa = document.getElementById('summa');
  var people_num = document.getElementById('people_num');

  var sobstv_fio = document.getElementById('sobstv_fio');
  var date1 = document.getElementById('date1');
  var passport = document.getElementById('passport');
  var passport_date = document.getElementById('passport_date');
  var passport_place = document.getElementById('passport_place');
  var passport_kod = document.getElementById('passport_kod');
  var index1 = document.getElementById('index1');
  var propiska = document.getElementById('propiska');

  var strah_fio = document.getElementById('strah_fio');
  var date2 = document.getElementById('date2');
  var passport2 = document.getElementById('passport2');
  var passport_date2 = document.getElementById('passport_date2');
  var passport_place2 = document.getElementById('passport_place2');
  var passport_kod2 = document.getElementById('passport_kod2');
  var index2 = document.getElementById('index2');
  var propiska2 = document.getElementById('propiska2');

  var btn = document.getElementById('submit');
  var btn2 = document.getElementById('submit2');
  var btn3 = document.getElementById('submit3');

  summa.value != '' && people_num.value != '' ? btn.disabled = false : btn.disabled = true;

  sobstv_fio.value != '' && date1.value != '' && passport.value != '' &&
    passport_date.value != '' && passport_place.value != '' && passport_kod.value != '' &&
    index1.value != '' && propiska.value != '' ? btn2.disabled = false : btn2.disabled = true;

  strah_fio.value != '' && date2.value != '' && passport2.value != '' &&
    passport_date2.value != '' && passport_place2.value != '' && passport_kod2.value != '' &&
    index2.value != '' && propiska2.value != '' ? btn3.disabled = false : btn3.disabled = true;


}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a disabled>Общее</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class=""><a disabled>Собственник</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class=""><a disabled>Страхователь</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class=""><a disabled>Авто</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class=""><a disabled>Водитель</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class=""><a disabled>Файлы</a></li>

</ul>

<br><br>
<!-- Tab panes -->

<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    <h4 class="text-center">Стоимость оформления 300р</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Страховка</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="strahovka" id="strahovka" required>
      <option value="Ограниченная">Ограниченная</option>
      <option value="Неограниченная">Неограниченная</option>
     </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Прицеп</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="pricep" id="pricep" required>
      <option value="Есть">Есть</option>
      <option value="Нет">Нет</option>
     </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Категория</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category" required>
      <option selected="selected" disabled value="Не указано">Не указано</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
      <option value="E">E</option>
     </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Кол-во мест в автобусе если автобус,газель</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="number" name="people_num" id="people_num" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control" maxlength="255">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Цель ОСАГО</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="cel_osago" onchange="check();" required>
      <option value="Купля-продажа">Купля-продажа</option>
      <option value="Продление">Продление</option>
     </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Сумма</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="number" name="summa" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" id="summa" class="form-control" maxlength="255" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <button type="button" disabled id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-next" href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-next="1">Далее</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Собственник ФИО</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="sobstv_fio" id="sobstv_fio" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control" maxlength="255" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Дата рождения</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_date" maxlength="10" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Паспорт (серия и номер)</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="passport" id="passport" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_passport" maxlength="12" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Дата выдачи паспорта</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="passport_date" id="passport_date" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_date" maxlength="10" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Кем выдан</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="passport_place" id="passport_place" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control" maxlength="255" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Код подразделения</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="passport_kod" id="passport_kod" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_passport_kod" maxlength="7" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Индекс</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="index1" id="index1" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_index" maxlength="7" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Прописка (Как в паспорте)</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="propiska" id="propiska" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control" maxlength="255" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-next" href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-next="0">Назад</button>
      <button type="button" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" id="submit2" class="btn btn-success btn-next" href="#tab3" aria-controls="tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-next="2">Далее</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Страхователь ФИО</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="strah_fio" id="strah_fio" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control" maxlength="255" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Дата рождения</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="date2" id="date2" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_date" maxlength="10" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Паспорт (серия и номер)</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="passport2" id="passport2" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_passport" maxlength="12" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Дата выдачи паспорта</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="passport_date2" id="passport_date2" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_date" maxlength="10" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Кем выдан</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="passport_place2" id="passport_place2" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control" maxlength="255" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Код подразделения</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="passport_kod2" id="passport_kod2" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_passport_kod" maxlength="7" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Индекс</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="index2" id="index2" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_index" maxlength="7" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Прописка</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="propiska2" id="propiska2" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control" maxlength="255" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-next" href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-next="1">Назад</button>
      <button type="button" onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" id="submit3" class="btn btn-success btn-next" href="#tab4" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-next="3">Далее</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову - добавлять активному табу класс `active` и при клике на кнопку `submit` проверять все дочерние поля на заполнение (либо только поля с классом `required`).

Comment: А можете набросать пример?

Comment: @lxxnutsxxl покажите HTML тоже, пожалуйста

Comment: @LEQADA  добавил код

Answer (score 3):

Пример был сделан до того, как автор представил свою разметку, но основную логику он демонстрирует.

```js
function toggleTab(){
  if (!checkForm()) {
    alert('Заполните все поля');
    return
  }
  var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
  for (var i=0;i<tabs.length-1;i++) {
    if (tabs[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      tabs[i].classList.remove('active');
      tabs[i+1].classList.add('active');
      break;
    }
  }
}

function checkForm() {
  var fields = document.querySelectorAll(".tab.active input.required");
  for (var i=0;i<fields.length;i++) {
    if (fields[i].value == '') {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
.tab {
  display:none;
}
.tab.active {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab active">
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 1 Field 1" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 1 Field 2" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 1 Field 3" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 1 Field 4" />
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 2 Field 1" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 2 Field 2" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 2 Field 3" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 2 Field 4" />
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 3 Field 1" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 3 Field 2" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 3 Field 3" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 3 Field 4" />
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 4 Field 1" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 4 Field 2" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 4 Field 3" />
  <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Tab 4 Field 4" />
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="toggleTab()">
  Next
</button>
```